# Separar texto por comas, excepto entre comillas, con expresiones regulares

Tags: java, regex

Tengo una cadena, la cual necesito separar por coma, excepto que la coma se encuentre dentro de comillas.

En mi código me separa por coma, pero también separa la coma que se encuentra dentro de la comilla.

```
package testSplit;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Created by J Michael on 26/04/2017.
 */
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = ",10010222,\"The Royal Bank of Scotland, Niederlassung Deutschland\",10105,Berlin";
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(text, ",|^[\",\"]$", false);
        System.out.println(tokens.countTokens());
        while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Otros ejemplos**

Para ser más exacto, cito este nuevo ejemplo, donde necesito 5 columnas por cada línea.

```
String s7=",12070024,Deutsche Bank Privat und Geschäftskunden,01968,"Senftenberg, NL"";
--> colum0=(vacio), 
    colum1=12070024,
    colum2=Deutsche Bank Privat und Geschäftskunden,
    colum3=01968,
    colum4=Senftenberg, NL
```

```
String s8=",12070024,Deutsche Bank Privat" und" Geschäftskunden,16856,"Kyrätz, Prägnitz"";
--> colum0=(vacio),
    colum1=12070024,
    colum2=Deutsche Bank Privat" und" Geschäftskunden,
    colum3=16856,
    colum4=Kyrätz, Prägnitz
```

Comment: Si bien tu pregunta ofrece información suficiente, sería recomendable aclarar si se permiten comillas escapadas dentro de un grupo de comillas. Por ejemplo `"aaa,\"bbb\\\"bbb\",ccc"` ... También  sería bueno comentar si un grupo de comillas está siempre balanceado o si hay que validarlo, incluyendo otros ejemplos, como se especifica en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Algunos casos que sería bueno que aclares si pueden ocurrir y qué resultado debería obtenerse: `",aa\\\"aa,\"bbb\\\"bbb\",ccc\"ccc\"ccc,\"ddd\"ddd,\""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La clave no es intentar separar, sino hacer coincidir con cada elemento.

Y el truco es agregar una coma antes del texto, luego es tan sencillo como que coincida por una coma seguida por `"[^"]*"` o por `[^,]*`.

Esta es la mejor forma de obtener cada elemento, garantizando que también se respeten elementos vacíos al principio o al final del texto.

#### Expresión Regular

```
,("[^"]*"|[^,]*)
```

- `,` - coincide con una coma literal
- `("[^"]*"|[^,]*)`
  Usamos los paréntesis, para capturar lo que coincida, y recuperarlo con [`matcher#group(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-). Dentro del grupo, dos opciones separadas con `|`:

  1. `"[^"]*"` - Comillas de apertura, seguidas de cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no son comillas, y comillas de cierre.
  2. `[^,]*` - Cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no son comas.

#### Código

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = ",(\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*)";
final String text  = ",10010222,\"The Royal Bank of Scotland, Niederlassung Deutschland\",10105,Berlin";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
// le agregamos una coma al texto para que coincida con el primer elemento
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("," + text);

int n = 0; //sólo para mostrar el número de elemento (opcional)

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print  ("Elemento " + ++n + ": ");
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

#### Resultado

```
Elemento 1: 
Elemento 2: 10010222
Elemento 3: "The Royal Bank of Scotland, Niederlassung Deutschland"
Elemento 4: 10105
Elemento 5: Berlin
```

#### Demo

http://ideone.com/k5inTE

---

#### Opción 2: omitir las comillas en el resultado

Si uno de los elementos está entre comillas y se desea obtener el texto sin las comillas en el resultado, podemos utilizar un grupo más, para obtener sólo el texto que está entre las comillas. Es decir, agregamos un par de paréntesis más:

```
,("([^"]*)"|[^,]*)
```

Y en el código, evaluamos si `matcher.group(2)` tiene algún valor.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
final String regex = ",(\"([^\"]*)\"|[^,]*)";
final String text  = ",12070024,Deutsche Bank Privat\" und\" Geschäftskunden,16856,\"Kyrätz, Prägnitz\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("," + text);

String elemento;
int n = 0;

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print  ("Elemento " + ++n + ": ");

    if (matcher.group(2) != null)
    {   // Elemento entre comillas?
        elemento = matcher.group(2); // Obtener el texto sin las comillas
    }
    else
    {
        elemento = matcher.group(1);
    }
    System.out.println(elemento);
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Xojnud

---

#### Opción 3: permitir que haya comillas escapadas dentro de las comillas

Para poder permitir comillas escapadas con una `\`, es necesario generar la excepción para todas las `\`s, y al mismo tiempo permitir una barra seguida de cualquier caracter.

```
final String regex = ",(\"[^\\\\\"]*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\\"]*)*\"|[^,]*)";
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/aE8PgC

Comment: Me pregunto si el OP también querría las comillas (inicial y final) en el resultado.

Comment: @Paul en todo caso sería sencillo crear otro grupo que obtenga el texto, pero la pregunta dice explícitamente "separar por comas"... De todas formas, hay más de un punto que debería aclarar, que lo comenté bajo la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano. he respondido a tu comentario agregando mas ejemplos.

Comment: @Paul, las comillas sí las necesito

Comment: @MichaelSalinasRios Gracias por agregar el comentario. De esta forma, responde a tus nuevos ejemplos de la forma que describiste. Agregué la opción 2 para que no devuelva las comillas de un elemento.

Comment: @Mariano, correcto. todo ok ! muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la siguiente expresión regular:

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=",|"$)|[^,"]+
```

Ejemplo:

```java
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\",|\"$)|[^,\"]+");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = ",10010222,\"The Royal Bank of Scotland, Niederlassung Deutschland\",10105,Berlin";
    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10010222
The Royal Bank of Scotland, Niederlassung Deutschland
10105
Berlin
```