# Expresión regular que seleccione las comas de un texto, excluyendo las comas que hay dentro de las comillas simples, en Java

Tags: java, regex

Tengo un problema con una expresión regular, y es que necesito seleccionar únicamente las comas de un texto, excluyendo las comas que hay dentro de las comillas simples.

El texto en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
9772,'Oficinas, Servi y cajeros',9664,7,0
```

Lo más que he conseguido es con esta expresión regular `[A-Za-z1-9'],[A-Za-z1-9']` la cual no me sirve ya que al hacer el .split() en java, también corto los otros dígitos y caracteres

Desconozco siquiera si se puede hacer lo que explico, así que agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: Separa primero por las comillas simples, y luego aplica lo que quieras hacer solo a las partes que van antes y después del texto.

Comment: que tal si primero haces un `split` por comillas simples, y a cada elemento restante le buscas las comas normales y luego concatenas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Separar texto por comas, excepto entre comillas, con expresiones regulares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65502/separar-texto-por-comas-excepto-entre-comillas-con-expresiones-regulares)

Comment: Había pensado en esa solución, pero me imaginaba que se podría hacer con una expresión regular. Pero si no encuentro la forma de hacerlo con la expresión regular, tendré que hacerlo así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado una solución valida para mi problema, esta expresión regular debería valer

`,(?=(?:[^']|'[^']*')*$)`

Answer (score 0):

Yo empezaría por separar el texto en tres secciones:

```
(.*,)'.*'(,.*)
```

En la expresión regular puedes ver dos grupos de captura que serían:

Entrada: `5658586,9772,'Oficinas, Servi y cajeros',9664,7,0`

- grupo 1: `5658586,9772,`
- grupo 2: `,9664,7,0`

Y a partir de la concatenación de los grupos de captura saltando el primer caracter del segundo grupo ya podrías procesar la información mediante la función split.

Comment: Justo acabo de dar con la solución, aún así muchas gracias por la idea!